# Interface cannot inherit from non-Interface IDispatch

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ (been doing C# since 1.0 beta).  I have been assigned upgrading a small c++ solution from VS 2005 to VS 2015 (it generates an .ocx file).  Most of it has been fine thus far, with the exception of a piece that has be going crazy.

I have the error "Interface class 'IEmail' cannot inherit from non-interface class 'IDispatch'"

```
__interface IEmail : IDispatch
{
    [id(1), helpstring("method Send")] HRESULT Send(BSTR SenderName, BSTR Sender, BSTR Recipient, BSTR Subject, BSTR Message,BSTR Server);
    [id(2), helpstring("method Shutdown")] HRESULT Shutdown(void);
    [id(3), helpstring("method Listen")] HRESULT Listen(BSTR Server, BSTR Account, BSTR Password);
    [id(4), helpstring("method DebugMode")] HRESULT DebugMode(LONG nMode);
};
```

IDispatch is defined as

```
    typedef interface IDispatch IDispatch;
```

Can somebody please show me how to get what the old code was accomplishing, to work again?  (simply explaining it to me in big c++ words, likely won't work)

Comment: This is not C++. It looks like Managed C++ by Microsoft.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it.  The typedef is weird, you'd only get that when the code is compiled as C instead of C++.   But that produces a very different error message for __interface.  You need an MCVE to get help.

Comment: The typedef is found in the OAldl.h file that comes with the Windows SDK 8.1.  I'm quite certain I am only supposed to view that file.  Besides the interface, or possibly not using an interface, how would I still implement the HRESULT for the 4 methods?

Comment: I changed __interface to interface and the build error goes away.  But what did I actually change?  Will that have some ill-effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VC++ has extensions including a code attribute system for C++ to enable generating COM type information directly out of C++ code. As part of these extensions, `__interface` identifies a pure virtual class which is a COM interface.

This is not a managed interface, this is an unmanaged interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50h7kwtb(v=vs.80).aspx

Essentially, the short version is `__interface` is correct, and `interface` is not. Since you have that typedef, it looks like some compiler option or compilation flag is wrong, and it is attempting to compile managed C++/CLR code.

Comment: Fantastic.  Exactly the kind of response I was looking for.  Now I will go through settings in an attempt to figure out which one could be wrong.  (this C++ stuff is SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO much harder than C#)